# asp.net inline code <%# MyboolVal %>

Tags: asp.net, inline-code

I must be missing something stupid here but I can not see it.  My work uses inline code on their sites, for example:

```
<panel runat="server" id="myid" visible='<%# MyboolVal %>'>
    some stuff
</panel>
```

That seems to work great for them, the panel will display when their condition is meet.

I am trying to use a similar approach on a site of mine at home (its late friday evening so asking my boss is not the best idea at this point).  I can not get it to output anything at all.  I have tried it in the visible field which didn't work, so I thought I would just get it to write something to the screen:

```
<p>some text <%# String.Format("meeee {0}", Mybool) %></p>
```

But I do not get any output from the inline code.   the "some text" appears but no "meeee" or the bool value.

I am doing this inside a user control, at this moment but do not imagine that would be the cause.

any ideas please?

Thanks

EDIT....

OK so thanks to Freddy Rios for the reply I can get the text to appear but when I try that in:

```
Visible='<%= mybool %>'
```

I get the compilation error of:

Cannot create an object of type System.boolean from its string representation for the visible property.

I am confused as to what exactly is happening.  There must be part of the process under the bonnet I don't get.

EDIT 2:

I get the error on line 123:

```
<fieldset class="myclass" id="projectarea" runat="server" visible='<%= ShowProjectSearchArea %>'>
```

ShowProjectSearchArea is my bool value, set to false.

If I double click the error in the Error List window I get the following in a popup, which I have never seen before:

```
  Cannot open file '%1'. It might not be in the solution.
```

Comment: Can you include the line that the compile error is thrown on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using = instead of # in your version:

```
<p>some text <%= String.Format("meeee {0}", Mybool) %></p>
```

The # is for databinding, so in the original code there must be a call to DataBind somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have edited my question accordingly. :)

Comment: @Jon I meant the comment on using = on your inline version when you wanted to output the text. You can't use that with a property of a server control, in that case you can use your original one and call DataBind on your panel (or on the control that contains it).

Comment: OMG, your spot on.  The lightbulb came on as soon as I read the word "DataBind"... I knew I was missing something really stupid.  I would love to put it down to 1am coding but I think I was just being an idiot.  Thanks so much.  I have learnt a bit today, so thank you to all that helped.

Answer (score 14):

`<%#` is databinding tag which is used to set values to server side controls, especially databound controls.

`<%=` is shorthand of `Response.Write()`, it writes the value to the output. So we use it with static html elements.

Comment: ah ok, that makes sense then.  When using it in the Visible I am saying write a text value into a boolean field and its getting upset...

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem is because visible property expect value of type string and you are trying to set it with bool.try to cast your value to string

Cheers

Comment: I believe it is the opposite, that the visible property wants a boolean value.  I tried <%# String.Format("{0}", true) %>  so it would just put a string of true, but I get "Cannot convert type string to bool" compiler error

Comment: Settings properties that don't use string as type requires the <# %> syntax that the the runtime will automaticly match the types when databinding.

<%= %> is a shorthand for Response.Write and can never be used to set property-values to objects, since its just writing out the string as-is at the corresponding place in the OutputStream.