# Calling function in usercontrol inline code doesn't always work

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, inline-code

I have constructed an ASP.NET user control "Box.ascx" wtih the following code.

```
<div id="divContent" runat="server" visible='<%# AllowedToView(this.Privacy) %>'>
    Content
</div>
```

In the codebehind, "Box.ascx.cs" has the following code.

```
public string Privacy = string.Empty;
public bool AllowedToView(string privacy)
{
    return true;
}
```

When I use this control in a repeater, AllowedToView() function is hit. If I use this control without a repeater, AllowedToView() function isn't called. I want to know why this weird situation happens and how can I make the control call the AllowedToView() function when used without repeater.

**Details are below.**

I use this control in a repeater in "Default.aspx".

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpRecords" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <uc1:Box ID="myBox" runat="server" RecordID = '<%# Eval("RecordID") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The repeater is databound in "Default.aspx.cs" with the following code:

```
DataTable dt = FillTable();
rpRecords.DataSource = dt;
rpRecords.DataBind();
```

I use the "Box.ascx" control in "ShowBox.aspx" with the following code.

```
<body>
    <uc1:Box ID="myBox" runat="server" />
</body>
```

I give values to the user control from the codebehind with the following code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myBox.RecordID = "1";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in another answer, the # means it will require databinding to be executed.

So to answer your question "How to make it run outside of the repeater" the simple answer is to call `myBox.DataBind()`.

Your question is very similar to [asp.net inline code <%# MyboolVal %>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850424/asp-net-inline-code-myboolval).  The problem is that <%= is equal to Response.Write and outputs straight HTML, so it won't work when setting the visible property.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the # but instead = in the ASP tag. Pretty sure # is only for databinding events and that's why it works in a repeater because a repeater performs a databound for rendering.

Check this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2007/02/13/the-difference-between-lt-and-lt-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: since I was getting some error when I used = sign, I had preferred #. But you are right. It is good that you reminded me # is for databinding. The article was very helpful. I will make databinding then. Like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8326019/931378) answer, I just put Page.DataBind(); in the Page_Load() of ShowBox.aspx.cs and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Im no expert on webforms but i think that your problem is that you are trying to databind that method and thats not working for you, try putting it in a <%= AllowedToView(this.Privacy) %>

Comment: <%= "" %> is equivelant to Response.Write and does not work when setting properties on server controls.